# Binary search through CSV column which may contain duplicates

Tags: python, binary-search

Using `Pandas` I have read a CSV file accessed through FTP. The first column `Code` values are sorted like so:

> PA0000357, 
>   PA0000358,
>   PA0000359,
>   PA0000359,
>   PA0000360,
>   PA0000380 ...

The codes may have duplicate numbers. I need to return all rows that match a given code. Since the numbers are sorted I was thinking to use `bisect` but I'm not sure if or how it works with duplicate codes.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r, sep=',', index_col=None, parse_dates=['Date'], 
                   usecols=['Code', 'PT Code', 'Value'])
```

`data` is a dataframe with the`Code` column I need to search through. Is it worth it to use `bisect` or shall I just go for `in`? The amount of data is around 500 rows.

Comment: Why not `data[data['Code'] == "PA0000357"]`?

Comment: @vpekar Sure that would work, I was just wondering whether it was worth it to do it non linearly.

Answer (score 0):

It's classic problem with binary search.
you should change the range search (not just the middle index only).
Ex:
PA0000357, PA0000358, PA0000359, PA0000359, PA0000360, PA0000380 ...

if meet PA0000359, you should run left and right to find the correct range.
an because you are using Py, please just use in/find. (500 is small number)